# Tie down to a function

Tags: angular, typescript

I have this code here, it is kinda messy so I want to tide it down to a function so later on I can recall it. The function should take in an array of text and a Model and maybe a timer. It tries to rotate the text and change the value of the Model after a set amount of time. I'm new to Angular 2 so I'm not sure which is the best way to do this.

```
import { 
  Component, OnInit,
  trigger, state, animate, transition, style 
} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  animations: [
    trigger('visibilityChanged', [
      state('true' , style({ opacity: 1, transform: 'scale(1.0)' })),
      state('false', style({ opacity: 0, transform: 'scale(0.0)'  })),
      transition('1 => 0', animate('500ms')),
      transition('0 => 1', animate('900ms'))
    ])
  ]
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
  fancyText: string;
  isVisible : boolean = true;

  constructor() {
    var textArr = ['Fancy', 'Text', 'Blinking', 'Alot']
    var curNewsIndex = 0
    this.fancyText = textArr[curNewsIndex]
    setInterval(() => {
      ++curNewsIndex
      if (curNewsIndex >= textArr.length) {
          curNewsIndex = 0
      }
      this.isVisible = !this.isVisible
      setTimeout(() => {
        this.fancyText = textArr[curNewsIndex]
        this.isVisible = !this.isVisible
      }, 500)
    }, 2000)
  }

  ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Thanks you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `constructor` only for initializing your model. Don't use it for doing any logic work like you are doing.
Instead use `ngOnInit` block:

```
    export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
      fancyText: string;
      isVisible : boolean = true;
       textArr :Array<string>;  

      constructor() {
      this.textArr = ['Fancy', 'Text', 'Blinking', 'Alot'];
      }

      ngOnInit() {
        funcToTie(textArr){
         this.textArr = textArr;
          var curNewsIndex = 0;
          this.fancyText = this.textArr[curNewsIndex];
          setInterval(() => {
          ++curNewsIndex
          if (curNewsIndex >= this.textArr .length) {
              curNewsIndex = 0
          }
          this.isVisible = !this.isVisible
          setTimeout(() => {
            this.fancyText = this.textArr[curNewsIndex]
            this.isVisible = !this.isVisible
          }, 500)
        }, 2000);
   }
    }
    }
```

Comment: Is there anyway to pass in the `fancyText` into the function and make it update inside the function. I want to make the function accessible for other component as well too. I tried but the function doesn't print the updated value in template.